# Bitbucket enforce prefixes to keep developers from creating branches at the root

Tags: git, bitbucket

Under origin I'd like to keep the root level relatively clean with just the develop and perhaps the master branch.  All the features, hotfixes, releases etc, I'd like to be created under the appropriate prefixes.  Most of the time people are following this, but then some are not.

Is there a way to enforce branches to be created only under a prefix?

Right now the remote looks like this

origin
   DC-123_Account_Creation
   DC-124_Permissions_Setup
   develop
   HEAD
   master
   ^feature
      DC-456_Repository_Setup

DC-123 & DC-124 are out of place.  I either have to let the errant branches ride until completed and merged or check them out and manually rename them to use the prefix and check them back in.  Then the developer gets irritated because their branch has moved and they have changes etc etc...

Since they won't play by the rules, can I remove their ability not to?

Answer (score 0):

How about not allowing them to write on origin and let only someone more "sensible" about the subject to take care of that? Given git's dynamic nature, I'm sure you can use something like a gatekeeper to take care of pulling from the "misbehaving" guys. https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows (Integration manager workflow)

Comment: that's too complicated. If bitbucket knows the branch-prefixes why there isn't a way to enforce them?